# multiple plots with multple datas and a lot of scaling issues

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to compare two sets of data for multiple locations on an individual chart for each location.. data has structure

```
gw <- well.id    date    benzene    bgs
```

bgs is depth to water (below ground surface) in feet. (I want to reverse this axis)
benzene ranges from 3 to 9 in some wells, and from .0001 to .01 in others....

I want to plot benzene concentrations so they overlap with depth to water for a visual correlation between the two data sets...

please see this excel example plot:
[image]

here you can find the [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B683f4SoyAjUNTVoV2tfcUpyaTg/view?usp=sharing)

aspects i have in mind are one data in reverse axis, scaled y values unique to each well location and data set... and the ability to pull subsets of the plots (like only the wells that show a correlations change in the most recent year)

I am approaching it like so...

```
setwd("~/my_ws")
gw <- read.csv("gw_cbp.csv")
gw


library(ggplot2) # Load the library

p <- ggplot(gw, aes(x=Date, y=Benzene)) + # Tell ggplot what you're plotting 
  geom_point() + #Tell ggplot it's a scatter plot
  geom_line() + # and i want lines
  facet_wrap(~ Well.ID) + # Plot one chart for each ID
  facet_grid(Date ~ Benzene, scales="free_y") ##not working... i know my syntax is wrong, just not sure how to fix it... 

p +
aes(x = Date, y = bgs)+
scale_y_reverse( y = bgs) # Reverse the axis
facet_grid(Date ~ bgs, scales="free_y")  ## still not working..
```

I know I am trying to scale my y axes individually, both unique to each location(well.id) and data set (benzene *and* bgs) and only one in reverse (bgs) as well as put the second y axis on the other side of the chart...but I am not getting it right.

as always, any help would be great,

ZR

Comment: See also [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/how-to-use-ggplot2-make-plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another) and [**here**](https://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2)

Comment: I will look into them, thanks... might not be exactly what I need but will post back soon

Comment: I have found what I need, I think... thank you for the info. I will post a specific answer when I hash it out.